# Error reading returned value from passing struct pointer to pthread_exit() in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthread-join, pthread-exit

I'm trying to pass pointers to struct lower_hyper_id from a thread to the main thread, by the means of pthread_exit() function, that would compare and output the value in the struct. However, i receive an error (Segmentation fault) when i am trying to use the returned value and cast it to the struct.

thread that creates and returns the struct:

```
void *compute(void *arg){
   lower_hyper_id *data = (lower_hyper_id *)malloc(sizeof(lower_hyper_id));

   //some code
   //i debug the program, and at this point, the struct i want
   //to return has the values i want.

   pthread_exit((void *)data);
}
```

in the main:

```
lower_hyper_id l_hyper_id;

int main(){
    void *ap_state;
    lower_hyper_id values;
    void *ret;

    //some code

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_FILTERING_THREADS; i++)
    {
        s = pthread_join(filtering_threads[i], (void *)&ret);
        //some error checking 

        values = *((lower_hyper_id *)ret);  //this is where i receive the error

        if (values.lowest_cost <= l_hyper_id.lowest_cost)
        {
            l_hyper_id.hyper_id = values.hyper_id;
            l_hyper_id.lowest_cost = values.lowest_cost;
        }
        free(ret);
}
```

I have already looked at answers in the stackoverflow such as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887214/pthread-exit-issues-returning-struct), but it hasn't helped me resolving this. I actually changed the code to be exactly equal to the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12887235/7213999), but still it gives me an error.

Comment: Do you test `ret` against `NULL` *before* dereferencing it?

Comment: @alk indeed... i tried it and if i do  if(ret == NULL), the ret is NULL. any way to fix this?

Comment: No idea, well, I could guess, what I won't, as you do not show the complete/relevant code.

Comment: Probably unrelated but casting `&ret` to `void*` is useless and misleading. `pthread_join` expects a `void**`, which `&ret` is.

Comment: Check for early returns in `compute`.

Comment: Few, if any, of the casts in this thing are needed, and they have every reason *not* to be in the code. Get rid of them. More characters != better code. Also, strip all of the `// some code` code you concluded couldn't possibly be part of your problem. Alloc some memory, start a do-nothing thread with pointer to that memory as the user-arg, return that pointer through `pthread_exit`, and reap it from `pthread_join`. If you can't make that work `// some code`is irrelevant. Further, if you *can* make that work, then `// some code` is the *problem*.

Answer (score 0):

You're not testing if malloc returned NULL. That could be an issue if you're allocing a large chunk and the allocation can fail.
Other than that, I don't think the problem is in the return value passing.

`pthread_exit()`ing with a `malloc`d pointer should work just fine.

A minimial working example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void *compute (void *arg)
{
    printf("thread=%llx\n", (unsigned long long)pthread_self());
    size_t sz = strlen("hello world")+1;
    char *ret = malloc(sz+1);
    if(ret) memcpy(ret, "hello world", sz+1);
    return ret;
}
int main()
{
    printf("thread=%llx\n", (unsigned long long)pthread_self());
    pthread_t ptid;
    int er;
    if((er=pthread_create(&ptid,0,compute,0))) return errno=er,perror(0),1;
    void *retval;
    if((er=pthread_join(ptid,&retval))) return errno=er,perror(0),1;
    printf("thread returned: %s\n", (char*)retval);
    free(retval);

}
```

Comment: In the compute function, do you mean "pthread_exit(ret)" or "return ret"?

Comment: @DiogoSoares `return`ing `ret` from the root function of a thread is equivalent to calling `pthread_exit(ret)`.  You can call `pthred_exit(ret);` explicitly instead of `return`ing if you want to. It shouldn't change the result.